# SslStream read all bytes

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

When i am try to read from SslStream function Read() is never end if i am not set connection timeout but if i do i've got timeout exception. This guy have the same problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.read.aspx. I don't what to do here the code

```
    public byte[] ReadBytes()
    {
        this.bufferGlobal.Clear();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[this.bufferSize];
        int recv = this.stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (recv != 0)
        {
            addBytes(buffer, ref bufferGlobal, recv);
            recv = this.stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                
        }
        return (byte[])this.bufferGlobal.ToArray(typeof(byte));
    }
```

Thx in advance.

**UPD:**

i think i find the answer. I can set read timeout on SslStream equal one, thats value does not make sense for socket alive (its mean you can download huge files and don't worry about SslStream he wouldn't close connection or interupt recieve data). I just testing this solution but seems works fine. Thx everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from a network stream, which means *you will not encounter the end of stream until the other side closes its half of the connection*. It isn't enough for it to stop sending data. So, make your other program close the connection after it has sent all data it intends to.

Comment: I write library for communication with google service and i can't ask google close connection after transmition all data. As i see when i try to connect to diferent sites everything fine except "Corporation of Good" ))) Maybe we have another ways to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

The stream won't end until the connection is closed. This is the nature of all streams of an unknown length.

You either need to know the length ahead of time or you need to keep reading until the connection is closed. A common way is to transmit the byte length of the stream as a 64bit int. So the first 8 bytes of your stream is read into an int64, then the rest is the data.

Typically one reads in a stream one "buffer" at a time.

pseudo code

while(!Stream.end)
{
 i = Stream.Read(buffer, buffer.length)
 DestStream.Write(buffer, i)
}

Comment: I'm not sure how Google's protocol works, but I would assume it's a web protocol. There are many ways to solve this issue, but if you're working with someone else's protocol, you need to do it a way that is compatible.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't help more, but good luck. Hopefully someone who knows more will say something.

Answer (score 0):

bit late but I am using msdn code with following modification

```
if (sb.ToString().IndexOf("a OK") != -1 || sb.ToString().IndexOf("a BAD") != -1 || sb.ToString().IndexOf("a NO") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this working patch if it works for you:

```
                int bytesRead = 0;
                string chunkString = "";
                do
                {
                    byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];
                    bytesRead = sslStream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
                    ApplicationHelper.ApplicationLogger.WriteInfoLog("Bytes Received " + bytesRead);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        chunkString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        responseXML += chunkString;
                    }

                }
                while (!chunkString.EndsWith(EOF));
```